# Enum in Abstract Class definition - Python

Tags: python, enums, abstract-class, pydantic

I need to use `Enum` inside of an abstract class definition, but I don't know how to do so. I am trying to do following:

```
class ProcurementChannelBase(ABC, BaseModel):
    @abstractmethod
    @unique
    class CounterParty(Enum):
        pass

    @abstractmethod
    @unique
    class Market(Enum):
        pass

    counterparty_name: CounterParty
    commodity: Commodity
    market: Market
    trading_channel: TradingChannel
    subject_to_margining: bool
    settlement_type: SettlementType

    @validator("counterparty_name", pre=True)
    def better_validation_message(cls, counterparty: str) -> str:  # noqa: N805
        if counterparty not in [cp.value for cp in cls.CounterParty]:
            raise ValueError(
                f"Counterparty name {counterparty} is not a valid counterparty name! Check the spelling and trailing spaces!"
            )
        return counterparty
```

And then I am using:

```
class ProcurementChannel(ProcurementChannelBase):
    @unique
    class CounterParty(Enum):
        BLA1 = "bla1"
        BLA2 = "bla2"


    @unique
    class Market(Enum):
        TEST1 = "test1"
        TEST2 = "test2"
```

The code is runnig, even the validation `better_validation_message` works, but then the build-n pydantic validations are failing due to:

```
counterparty_name
  value is not a valid enumeration member; permitted:  (type=type_error.enum; enum_values=[])
market
  value is not a valid enumeration member; permitted:  (type=type_error.enum; enum_values=[])
```

Any idea how to use `Enum` in abstract class definition? Thanks!